# Put JSON data into html form input checkbox with PHP

Tags: php, html, json, laravel, laravel-5

I want to put json data into html form input checkbox with laravel blade.

I have multiple input checkbox values as `test[]`,

Then I try use `htmlspecialchars` to print values into input.

If my frontend check this input, backend use print_r is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"value1":"tool_ad_id","value2":"\u65e5\u4ed8"}
    [1] => {"value1":"ad_group1","value2":"\u30c4\u30fc\u30eb\u5e83\u544aID"}
)
```

but I use `return $request->test['0']['value1'];`  can't get a value.

I want to get 'value1' and 'value2'.

**PHP Laravel**

```
@foreach($as as $key => $value)
      <div class="col s6 m4 l3 blue-grey lighten-5">
      <?php
            $data = ['value1' => $value['en'] ,'value2' => $value['jp'] ];
            $data_total = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data));
       ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test5{{ $key }}" value="{{$data_total}}" name="test[]" />
        <label for="test5{{ $key }}">{{$value['jp']}}</label>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
return $request->test['0']['value1'];
```

**Error message**

```
Illegal string offset 'value1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[0] => {"value1":"tool_ad_id","value2":"\u65e5\u4ed8"}
Index => String
```

PHP **does not** parse JSON, you are receiving the JSON as normal string. Therefore, in order to convert it to a PHP object with properties correspongind to the keys, you need to use `json_decode()`.

Try `$test = json_decode($request->test['0'], true)`, and then access values off the `$test` variable.

```
$value1 = $test['value1'];
$value2 = $test['value2'];
```

Comment: thanks your reply~!  but i want to get 'value1' and 'value2' , i try json_decode($request->test['0']['value1'], true) is also Illegal string offset 'value1'..

Comment: Do not try `json_decode($request->test['0']['value1'], true)` just `json_decode($request->test['0'], true)` and then try and access 'value1'